# Java Concurrency spec ?: Is an update to a field inside a synchronized block visible to all threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

Say you have this code:

```
private Object lockObject = new Object();
private Integer myValue = new Integer(0);

public void update(){
 synchronized(lockObject){
  System.out.println(myValue);
  myValue++;
 }
}
```

Now, `myValue` is neither `synchronized` on nor is it marked `volatile`. However, the only way to mutate it is with the `update()` method. [DZone's refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency) on core java concurrency says that updates to fields in a syncronized block are seen by all threads. I was unsure if this meant the syncronized object only (lockObject) or any field (like myValue).

Can anyone elaborate on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All field updates within the synchronized block are guaranteed to be visible to other threads so long as they *also* synchronize on the same object before reading. So long as you synchronize *all access* to the shared mutable state, you should see all the updates.

Alternatively, if you really only have a counter, use `AtomicInteger` :)

Comment: So if I have another thread reading `myValue`, but it didn't synchronize on `lockObject`, then it's _possible_ it wouldn't see the update?

Comment: @exabrial: That's my understanding, yes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I <3 AtomticInteger :) I was just using a `++` here as a simple example

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

1. Thread1 executing `System.out.println(myValue);` inside the synchronized block outputs the current value of `myValue`.
2. Thread2 executing `System.out.println(myValue);` *before* Thread1 increments `myValue` will get the same value of `myValue` as in step 1.
3. Thread1 increments `myValue` inside the synchronized block.
4. Thread2 executing `System.out.println(myValue);` *might* get the new value of `myValue` as set by Thread1.